# Background shows in Mozilla but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

I've applied a background to a div. it shows in mozilla but not in chrome.

Here is my code

```
#product-header {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-70deg, #578EA3, #34495E) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Having only a `-moz` vendor-prefixed value tells you something, no? Just remove the prefix.

Comment: Well, I knew its something to do with `-moz`, I removed it but still didnt worked.

Comment: The syntax seems correct, the standards-compliant `linear-gradient()` is supported in Chrome and Firefox http://caniuse.com/css-gradients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used background property which is explicit for mozilla only. You should add one suitable for chrome:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(-70deg, #578EA3, #34495E) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

You could also use plain linear-gradient like:

```
linear-gradient(-70deg, #578EA3, #34495E) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Putting it allthogether:

```
#product-header {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-70deg, #578EA3, #34495E) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-70deg, #578EA3, #34495E) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background: linear-gradient(-70deg, #578EA3, #34495E) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: No problem ;). I can also add that if you're aiming for cross-browser compatibility there are some more prefixes: -o- (for opera) and -ms- for IE